# MY SQL, Get column name in a parent child relationship from same table by getting child values from another table

Tags: mysql

table 1 and table 2

In table 1:

```
Question ID Question Name
    1             a
    2             b
    3             c
    4             d
    5             e
    6             f
    7             g
```

In table 2, Parent question ID has relation with child question id which are derived from table 1:

```
parent Question ID  child Question ID
    1               2
    1               5
    1               4
    1               3
    6               7
```

Now i need the answer to get result like this:

```
Question ID Question Name
    1            a
    2            b
    5            e
    4            d
    3            c
    6            f
    7            g
```

Please provide the mysql query for it. Thanks in advance

Comment: You will likely need to do two queries, and merge the results together on the application side. What language are you using to digest the results of the query?

Comment: Is there a column in `Table2` that guarantees it can be queried in exactly the order you've shown it?

Comment: hello joe Iam using coldfusion..

Comment: @Ed Gibbs. In table 2, Question order is there, as 1,2,3.

Comment: @anter05 - I can see how `Table2` defines the order for `Table1`. The problem you have is that there's no way to be sure that `Table2` itself can be read in the proper order. It looks like you're relying on the "natural order" in which the rows were entered, and that's not something you should ever rely on. Put another way, there's no `Table2` column where you can do an `ORDER BY` and have it come out as `1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 7`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, but from what I can glean, I'd do something to this effect:

```
SELECT 
  table2.child_question_id, 
  table1.question_name 
FROM 
  table2, 
  table1 
WHERE 
  table2.child_question_id = table1.question_id
```

At a basic glance it looks to get the data how you need it!

-Edit, I'm sure that I'm missing something from your question, but stuck my solution up anyway, hopefully it'll be of some use!

Comment: I need the main question id, followed by the child question ids, and the next main question id followed by its child ids